# Help identifying this plant with purple and green fleshy leaves

Tags: identification, houseplants, evergreens

I bought a house a few months ago and this plant was in the terrace. It was less more than a dry stick in a pot, and I actually thought it was already dead (after a whole hot and dry south-east spanish summer) but I started watering it anyway in a daily basis, and apparently it likes it: now it has become this nice plant.

[image]

Could you tell me which kind of plant it is?

Thanks!

Comment: The leaves suggest to me maybe it's some kind of succulent?